# #import rename namespace MSXML not working when move to server 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-server-2012, msxml

We had this code, which worked when we compiled on server 2008:

```
#import <msxml6.dll>  rename("DOMDocument","DOMDocumentT"), named_guids raw_interfaces_only rename_namespace("MSXML")

...

hr = pXMLDoc.CreateInstance( MSXML::CLSID_DOMDocumentT );
```

Now i get this error:

```
error C2039: 'CLSID_DOMDocumentT' : is not a member of 'MSXML'
```

Unfortunately I don't know enough about COM (this is legacy code) to know what to do.

Any ideas?